# How can I get the result of the input from the first method?

Tags: java, methods, overloading

```
import java.util.*;
public class OverloadingFG2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
       userenter();
       userenter(false);
    }
    public static void userenter(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your Fullname: ");
        String fullname = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
        System.out.println("M for Male F for female: ");
        String sex = input.nextLine();
        String male = "M";
        String female = "F";
        
        if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(male)){
            System.out.println("Hello Mr. " + fullname + " Welcome to the party!");
        }else if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(female)){
            System.out.println("Hello Ms. " + fullname + " Welcome to the party!");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    public static boolean userenter(boolean yes){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Are you with a company? Yes/No");
        String ans = input.nextLine();
        String y = "yes";

        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
            userenter("withmate");
        }else
            System.out.println("Have a Good Day ahead!");
        return yes;
    }
    public static void userenter(String withmate){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your mates Fullname: ");
        String fullname = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.println("");
        
        System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
        System.out.println("M for Male F for female: ");
        String sex = input.nextLine();
        String male = "M";
        String female = "F";
        
        if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(male)){
            System.out.println("Hello Mr. " + fullname + " Welcome to the party!");
        }else if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(female)){
            System.out.println("Hello Ms. " + fullname + " Welcome to the party!");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    
    
}
```

**
I have trouble getting the result from the first user. The plan is to greet both of them but I can't seem to get the value of the other method I'm using.
The goal is to use overloading and to greet the both of them now I just have a problem on greeting the both of the user. I mean greet them together
**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to your question:

In that case yes, you'll have to create a global variable for their gender. I've simplified the code for you for demonstration:

```
import java.util.*;
public class OverloadingFG2 {

public static String fullName1;
public static String gender1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    userenter();
    userenter(false);
}

public static void userenter() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Fullname: ");
    fullName1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
    System.out.println("M for Male F for female: ");
    String sex = input.nextLine();
    gender1 = (sex.equalsIgnoreCase("M") ? "Mr. " : "Ms. ");

    System.out.println("Hello " + gender1 + fullName1 + " Welcome to the party!");
    System.out.println("");
}

public static boolean userenter(boolean yes) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you with a company? Yes/No");
    String ans = input.nextLine();
    String y = "yes";

    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(y)) {
        userenter("withmate");
    } else
        System.out.println("Have a Good Day ahead!");
    return yes;
}

public static void userenter(String withmate) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your mates Fullname: ");
    String fullname = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
    System.out.println("M for Male F for female: ");
    String sex = input.nextLine();
    String gender2 = (sex.equalsIgnoreCase("M") ? "Mr. " : "Ms. ");

    System.out.println("Hello " + gender2 + fullname + " and " + gender1 + fullName1 + " Welcome to the party!");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: Can you merge your answers?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I am understanding the question correctly. Do you want to greet both of the users towards the end?

Then you'll need to set up a global variable, like so:

```
import java.util.*;
public class OverloadingFG2 {

public static String fullName1;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    userenter();
    userenter(false);
}
public static void userenter(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your Fullname: ");
    fullName1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
    System.out.println("M for Male F for female: ");
    String sex = input.nextLine();
    String male = "M";
    String female = "F";

    if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(male)){
        System.out.println("Hello Mr. " + fullName1 + " Welcome to the party!");
    }else if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(female)){
        System.out.println("Hello Ms. " + fullName1 + " Welcome to the party!");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
public static boolean userenter(boolean yes){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Are you with a company? Yes/No");
    String ans = input.nextLine();
    String y = "yes";

    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase(y)){
        userenter("withmate");
    }else
        System.out.println("Have a Good Day ahead!");
    return yes;
}
public static void userenter(String withmate){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your mates Fullname: ");
    String fullname = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Are you Male or Female?");
    System.out.println("M for Male F for female: ");
    String sex = input.nextLine();
    String male = "M";
    String female = "F";

    if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(male)){
        System.out.println("Hello Mr. " + fullname + " and " + fullName1 + " Welcome to the party!");
    }else if(sex.equalsIgnoreCase(female)){
        System.out.println("Hello Ms. " + fullname + " and " + fullName1 + " Welcome to the party!");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

}

Comment: How about for their salutations like Mr. and Ms. do I need to create another global variable?